# Can module react-redux by component like Angular?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

everybody. 
Today, I have a question for react-redux. 
I learned Angular and it has struct folder as follow for 1 component.

```
-people
  -people.component.css
  -people.component.ts
  -people.component.html
  -...
```

I can build like it with reactjs .

```
-people
  -index.jsx
  -style.css
```

My question : Can module react-redux by component like Angular ?

```
-people
   actions
      -xxx.js
   api
      -yyy.js
   reducers
      -zzz.js
   routers
      -kkk.js
   store
  -index.jsx
  -style.css
```

Is it OK ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOU CAN!

But, store is global -> you should set it on root component
If you use that structure, I think it will be difficult to share action, component.

That structure is quite similar: https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit.